# MySQL Returns PHP Associative Array - but I Can't Access Array Data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, associative-array

I have two records in the MySQL table. I am trying to use `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tableA` but I am not getting the results I am expecting.

The code below will echo `Array ( [0] => Array ( [cnt] => 2 ) )`:

```
// Count the amount of records in the table
$total = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM tableA", 'ARRAY_A' );

echo "Total Records:" . print_r( $total );
```

The code below echos nothing:

```
// Count the amount of records in the table
$total = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM tableA", 'ARRAY_A' );

echo "Total Records:" . $total[0]['total'];
```

How can I simplify this? What am I doing wrong? I'm racking my brain over this and I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php

$numRows = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM tableA");

echo $numRows;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm afraid this does not fix the issue - it still returns blank/empty.

Comment: First check whether query is working. If yes then try another wordpress functions to execute it. I think query is perfect one.Have you checked this ???

Comment: Yes I have, and it was my mistake - I did not take out the `, ARRAY_A` argument when I changed the function, I tried it and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome .....! Always take care of code that you paste from elsewhere.... Enjoy ........

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$total = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM tableA", 'ARRAY_A' );

echo "Total Records:" . $total[0]['cnt'];
```

thanks.

Comment: It is different, i have used $total[0]['cnt'] instead of your's $total[0]['total']

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM tableA";
$sth = $DC->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                
echo $result['total'];
```